# Creating a GET action method that takes in multiple params and returns a list of dates

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, api, asp.net-web-api

I am creating a Web API and the clients need to be able to make a GET request that returns a list of dates as JSON. The client will need to specify the following parameters in order to get a result:

```
startDate (datetime)  
endDate (datetime)  
offset (int)  
type (string)
```

I am assuming since this is a GET method the client has to pass all of the params in through the url.

I currently have an action method in my controller that looks like the following (I believe I currently have it setup so the params are passed as query string rather than in the URL):

```
public IActionResult Get(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, int offset = 0, string type = "defaultType")
{
    List<DateTime> sampleDates = new List<DateTime>()
    {
        new DateTime(2015, 1, 22),
        new DateTime(2015, 2, 22),
        new DateTime(2015, 3, 22),
        new DateTime(2015, 4, 22),
    };

    return Ok(sampleDates);
}
```

In the above example I am not doing anything with the params just yet since this is a test.

I am wondering if this is the correct way to create a function that takes multiple parameters and returns a list of dates. If it is could someone give me an example of what the URL might look like on the client end.

Additionally, would it be possible to have the user send in a JSON object as the params using POST?

I am trying to see what my options are since the API I am building will have several GET functions that take several random parameters that can't really be categorized as properties of objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the value in the route. Adding the param names to the route isn't required but it makes it clear to the user of your API what the intended params are.

```
[HttpGet, Route("api/sampledates/startdate/{startDate}/enddate/{endDate}/offset/{offset}/type{type}")]
public IActionResult Get(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, int offset = 0, string type = "defaultType")
{
    List<DateTime> sampleDates = new List<DateTime>()
    {
        new DateTime(2015, 1, 22),
        new DateTime(2015, 2, 22),
        new DateTime(2015, 3, 22),
        new DateTime(2015, 4, 22),
    };

    return Ok(sampleDates);
}
```

You can also use constraints to control the incoming params:

```
[HttpGet, Route("api/sampledates/startdate/{startDate:datetime}/enddate/{endDate:datetime}/offset/{offset:int:min(0)}/type{type}")]
```

Comment: So I guess it is pure preference whether I do it the way you showed me using the route or by using query string params. Isn't an advantage of query string params that they can be optional and entered in any order?

Comment: I'm pretty sure in my case the user is going to POST the params as JSON in the body and then I am going to return JSON. I will only be using GET for simple things.

Comment: You can still send optional params on a route by using a ? as you normally would. The only real advantage to using a structured route like in the example is when you are offering a public API. The user of your API should be able to "walk" the route to get the data they would expect. Example: /api/users/21 you would expect to get you the user with the ID of 21 but if you walk the route and remove the /21 you would expect to get all users. But you can certainly post an object with params if you have a bunch of them.

Answer (score 0):

**You can send your parameters in query string.**

```
 [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get([FromUri]DateTime startDate,[FromUri] DateTime endDate, [FromUri]int offset = 0, [FromUri]string type = "defaultType")
    {
        List<DateTime> sampleDates = new List<DateTime>()
        {
            new DateTime(2015, 1, 22),
            new DateTime(2015, 2, 22),
            new DateTime(2015, 3, 22),
            new DateTime(2015, 4, 22),
        };

        return Ok(sampleDates);
    }
```

**Send Parameters using query string as show below**

```
api/sampledates?startdate=startDate:datetime}&enddate={endDate:datetime}&offset={offset:int:min(0)}&type={type}
```